# Android 6, authentification issue with BLE Device, access to the LinkKey bits

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-6.0-marshmallow, pairing

I've got an issue about android 6 and BLE compatibility.

My app initiate a read request on a protected characteristic which launch the pairing display to enter the appropriate passcode. With the right pass code, the smartphone and the ble device are bonded just fine if it's with android < 6.0

I tried with an android 6.0.1 too but it keeps giving me the same message "Couldn't pair because of an incorrect PIN or passkey"

It's not a permission issue since i already get the position permission with ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION request.

It seems it's a problem about the LinkKey bits in the pairing request.
I need to access it and block it since the ble device is confused by the additional bit(s) in the pairing request (because of its use of the Bluetooth 4.0 and not 4.2).

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Some vendors have issues with Secure Connection pairing method. What is the BLE device implementation (Vendor, Version ?).

Comment: It's a Ti cc2540 using the Ti ble stack 1.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known bug in 1.4.0 of Ti BLE stack got [fixed in 1.4.1](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC254X_Release_Notes):

> Fix for CC254x host Bond Manager setParam configuration does not support M/S LinkKey enc exchange

Comment: y but is there no workaround to fix that from the android side, without changing the Ti BLE stack?

Comment: The issue is already fixed in the Android code since 2015 but many phone vendors are slow pushing out the update. Try with a Nexus phone with 6.0.1.