# Pairing Rejected By CC41-A

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I purchased a [BLE module HM-10](http://www.ebay.com/itm/311567433651) from eBay. But it is a CC41-A actually. Currently I’m working on an IoT project both for Android and IOS. I actually tried to connect this with the IOS mobile app and it connected successfully. But when I try to connect it to Android (Samsung Note 3 and Nexus 5) it rejects pairing. It simply gives an error message saying “Pairing Rejected By CC41-A”. [Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKurt.jpg).
Please help me to sort this problem.

Comment: Do you have a sniffer to see what happened ? You can find some for ~50$ (Nordic has one based on the nRF51)

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832903/android-6-authentification-issue-with-ble-device-access-to-the-linkkey-bits

Comment: @TimF I tried to pair the BLE from system settings. Then an error messaged popped up as "Paring rejected". What's the fault have I done. Doesn't the BLE need to be paired through system settings?

Comment: @Nipo No that is not related I think.

Comment: BLE is a complex protocol and there could be a lot of reasons for this kind of thing to happen. Without more data (logcat, sniffer)  only black magic can help you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to find a lot and finally got to know that BLE modules like HM-10 does not have a pairing mode. They connect directly through the app

Comment: Thanks for this and to excuse me saying thanks - here is some more info I found useful! https://rydepier.wordpress.com/2015/10/24/ibeacon-using-an-hm10-or-cc41a-bluetooth-4-unit/ -- Also the device only said it was a cc41a after a factory reset, till then I'd been looking for a hc-04 (the name it was broadcasting when I got it).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. It belongs on another site in the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the TYPE parameter to 3
using the AT commands (no need to press any button) it will work just like that

BAUD 9600 by default.

after changing it to TYPE 3 it worked for me, didn't get "pairing rejected"
But I'm still having trouble connecting to it via my APP
(working on that part)

Comment: Thank you. After changing it to TYPE=3 you need also to reset the device (AT+RESET). Pairing works OK.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. It belongs on another site in the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: This worked for me, but took a little tinkering: 1. Connect to BT module via serial connection to use AT commands (no need to do anything to enter at mode, just check baud rate, use both nl & cr and test with command "at") 2. "at+default" then "at+reset" to factory reset 3. "at+type3", "at+pin000000" and "at+reset" (pin has to be set to any 6 character number) 4. Now use a BLE Scanner App on your Android device to connect, enter your pin when connecting and then you have a connection, but you always have to use a ble scanner app to initiate connection, even after pairing once.